# Cotangent bundle of $SO(3)$

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification, lie-groups, lie-algebras, physics

This comes from physics, we know the configutation space of rigi body's motion is lie group $SO(3)$, and we know the phase space of the cinfiguration space is its cotangent bundle. So this tells us the phase space of rigid body's motion is $T^{*}(SO(3))= \bigcup T_gSO(3)$.

We first know $T_eG \cong \mathfrak g$. The lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ of $SO(3)$ is the 3-dimensional skey symmetric matrix = $\mathfrak{so}(n)=\left\{M \in \operatorname{Mat}(n \times n, \mathbb{R}) \mid M+M^{T}=0\right\}$.

Next we compute the $T_g (SO(3))$ for any $g\in SO(3)$. First take a vector $X\in T_e(SO(3))$, then we know $T_g(SO(3))= gX$ by differential left multiplication.  Obviously, this can be transfered in matrix language and matrix multiplication.

In a word, $T_g(SO(3))$= (any skew symmetric matrix) $\cdot$ (element g in $SO(3))$.

Since all the matrix is inverse to each other, so I believe we've solved how cotangent bundle looks like.

In a word, I think it looks like $SO(3)\cdot$ {$3$-dimensional skew-symmetric matrix}

So is my proof or calculation correct ?  And does this have a much prettier formula or a physical terminology ?

Comment: First, you're discussing the *tangent* bundle, not the cotangent bundle. Of course, if you put on an invariant metric, you can identify them. Second, you seem to have switched left-invariant vector fields to right in your displayed equation?